# Clarifications on training job parameters with Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

Im using the new Tensorflow object detection API.

I need to replicate training parameters used on a paper but Im a bit confused.
In the paper is stated

> When training neural network models, their base confguration is similar to that used to
> train on the COCO 2017 dataset. For the unambiguous comparison of the selected models, the total number of
> training steps was set to 100 equal to 100′000 iterations of learning.

Inside `model_main_tf2.py`, which is the script used to start the training, I can read the following:

```
"""Creates and runs TF2 object detection models.

For local training/evaluation run:
PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH=path/to/pipeline.config
MODEL_DIR=/tmp/model_outputs
NUM_TRAIN_STEPS=10000
SAMPLE_1_OF_N_EVAL_EXAMPLES=1
python model_main_tf2.py -- \
  --model_dir=$MODEL_DIR --num_train_steps=$NUM_TRAIN_STEPS \
  --sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=$SAMPLE_1_OF_N_EVAL_EXAMPLES \
  --pipeline_config_path=$PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH \
  --alsologtostderr
"""
```

Also, you can specify the `num_steps` and `total_steps` parameters in the `pipeline.config` file (used by the training script):

```
train_config: {
  batch_size: 1
  sync_replicas: true
  startup_delay_steps: 0
  replicas_to_aggregate: 8
  num_steps: 50000
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: .16
          total_steps: 50000
          warmup_learning_rate: 0
          warmup_steps: 2500
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
```

So, what Im not understanding is how should I map what is written in the paper with tensorflow parameters.
What is the `num steps` and `total_steps` inside the `pipeline.config` file?

What is the `NUM_TRAIN_STEPS` argument instead?
Does it overwrite config file steps or its a completely different thing?

If more details are needed feel free to ask.